# geom_mosaic and aes magic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the following [library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmosaic/vignettes/ggmosaic.html) for mosaic plots. In the documentation it provides the following example:

```
ggplot(data = fly) +
   geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(DoYouRecline, RudeToRecline), fill=DoYouRecline)
```

So the `DoYouRecline` and `RudeToRecline` are x and y variables in a plot, but for some reason they are combined with `product` function which returns a list of `name`s. How does geom_mosaic internally use `product(DoYouRecline, RudeToRecline)` in order to figure out that the two parameters need to be used for x and y axis?

The main problem that I have is that I need to have one of those attribute names as a variable, for instance something like this:

```
attr_name =  'foo'
ggplot(data = fly) +
   geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(DoYouRecline, attr_name), fill=DoYouRecline)
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can explore the Stat object with `ggmosaic::StatMosaic$...`, in this case most importantly I think `ggmosaic::StatMosaic$compute_layer`

Comment: or you mirror the repository and explore the source code directly